# How should I Design My Tables in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Let's say I'm trying to make a Football site, there will be teams and leagues. Each season, a team might be in different league. When each team plays a league match, the score for the team in the league will get updated. So my basic idea is this:

```
League
 ID
 Name
Team
 ID
 Name
```

Okay, so League and Team is Many-to-Many. I assume the relation table should be as follow:

```
League_Team
 League_ID
 Team_ID
```

But I need to insert some metadata for it as well, like "Wins", "Lost", "Points" and season. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is Doctrine referring to something specific?

Comment: @Jared the Doctrine ORM Framework, I'd say : http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a `Match` or `Game` table:

```
Match
 Home
 Visitor
 HomeScore
 VisitorScore
```

And then aggregate to determine points for a team, such as `SUM`.

Comment: If match gets large enough, doesn't that make quite a performance impact?